# rails polymorphic article comments auto create one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm test polymorphic relationship using article and comment

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I'm created one article used `foo = Article.create(title: "foo")`

problem is here

I'm using terminal `foo.comments.size` show 0

but in browser render comments that auto created one?

[image]

controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: are you sure that this comment wasn't previously created by hand, cause creating Article shouldn't create Comment by default as you said, try to clear comment table and close rails console and create a new article, close and reopen rails server too.

Comment: :), this little issue hide too deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating the instance in the view because the `Comment id: nil` means the comment was not persisted to the db.

maybe you are doing in your view something like `@article.comments.build`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found error is: `@article.comments.build`

should be `form_for [@article, @article.comments.build]`

```
<h1>show</h1>
<p><%= @article.title %></p>

<section id="comment-form">
    <%= form_for [@article, @article.comments.build] do |f| %>
        body: <%= f.text_field :body %>
        <br>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
</section>
comments size: <%= @article.comments.size %>
<ul> <%= render @article.comments %> </ul>
```

Comment: ask me any question